# Moving uploaded files in Socialengine

Tags: socialengine

I tried moving uploaded file through browse action in socialengine from /public/user/ to /Files/SE/ by using
1.
    $fileobj = new Zend_Cloud_StorageService_Adapter_FileSystem();
    $fileobj->moveItem($sourcePath, $destinationpath);

2. move_uploaded_file($sourcePath, $destinationpath);
   Both of these couldn't move the file. I have checked the paths too they are perfect and works with other frameworks

Comment: Any help on this?

Answer (score 0):

You should use API of `Storage` module which will allow you to create temporary files (when you need to resize images or convert videos) and then place them into public storage. This files will be tracked in `engine4_storage_files` table.

Answer (score 0):

I got it worked by using createSystemFile() function under storage > Model > DbTable > Files.php

I created a function similar to this and gave parent_type as the folder which I wanted to move in the files.